# Error while writing Visualforce Controller Extension

Tags: controller, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am trying to write my first controller extension, and I am running into an error:

Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST at line 26 column 34

This is the code that generated the error:

```
public class CustFinAcctRelatedList{
private households__Household__c RG;

private List<households__HouseholdMember__c> RGMembs;
private List<Account> Accts;
private List<Financial_Account__c> finAccts;

//Get Household Record from VisualForce Page//
public CustFinAcctRelatedList(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.RG = (households__Household__c)controller.getRecord();
}

public List<Financial_Account__c> getFinAccts()
{
    //Get Household Members (junction object between Account and Household) from Household//
    RGMembs = [
        SELECT id, households__Household__c, households__Account__c
        FROM households__HouseholdMember__c 
        WHERE households__HouseholdMember__c.households__Household__c = :RG.id
    ];

    //Get Accounts from Household Members (junction object between Account and Household)//
    Accts = [
        SELECT id
        FROM Account
        //****THE FOLLOWING LINE IS CAUSING THE ERROR****//
        WHERE Account.id IN :RGMembs.households__Account__c.id
    ];

    //Get Financial Account from Accounts//
    finAccts = [
        SELECT id, name, Client__r.name, Current_Value__c, Account_Type__c
        FROM Financial_Account__c
        WHERE Financial_Account__c.Client__c IN :Accts.id
    ];

    return finAccts;
}
}
```

Any idea why this error is being generated?

I am going to use the return data to create a custom related list on a Visualforce page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`RGMembs` is a list at this point so you need to use an indexer such as `RGMembs[0].households__Account__c.id`

You could also use the `LIMIT 1` syntax in your query as this will assign an object as the result of the query. Be careful though with this, if the query returns 0 rows then it will throw an exception.

Also in the RGMembs query you need to select the `households__Acount__c.id` otherwise you will run into a problem when you try to reference a field that wasn't queried in the Accts query.

Looking also at your `finAccts` query you will end up with the same concrete SObject error as you had in the earlier query. To fix this one simply remove the `.id` in your IN statement so it becomes `IN :Accts`

Hopefully that will help.

-- UPDATE --

Looking back at your code I don't think you need the middle query. The first query gives you all of the accounts that belong to the members in the household. You can then use this list of accounts to help you select all of the Financial Accounts related to those Account objects. I would go about achieving that like this:

```
Set<Id> RGMembers = new Set<Id>();

for(households__HouseholdMember__c member :  [SELECT households__Account__c.id FROM households__HouseholdMember__c WHERE households__HouseholdMember__c.households__Household__c = :RG.id]){
    RGMembers.add(member.households__Account__c.id);
}

finAccts = [SELECT id, name, Client__r.name, Current_Value__c, Account_Type__c FROM Financial_Account__c WHERE Financial_Account__c.Client__c.id IN :RGMembers];
```

Is this closer to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, I made some of the changes you suggested (like removing .id in the finAccts query), however, I don't fully understand your other suggestions.

However, each Household has several RGMembs, and I need any Account related to any RGMemb in the household, and then any Financial Account in any of those Accounts. Is there a way that I can use lists to generate this final list of "All Financial Accounts Related to the original Household"?

On your second point, because households_Account__c is a Lookup, isn't the __c the records ID and the __r the record itself?

Thanks again!

Comment: OK - first off: the reason you got the exception is because you referenced `RGMembs.households__Account__c` in the second query, given that RGMembs is a list you can't do this as there is no property called `households__Account__c` on the list. I'll edit my answer to include some code to sole the problem as I see it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out, but at first glance I think you're right about not needing the second query. I toyed with using a for loop, and now that you've done it, it looks like a good solution. I'll report back if this works, thanks again!

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test it thoroughly yet, but once I inserted it I was getting errors anywhere that you had appended a field with '.id', which I think was happening b/c the __c API name on a related object _is_ the 'id', whereas __r is the record itself. Once I removed the '.id' in a few places, it at least validated. I'll see if the rest of it works, but either way thanks a lot!

Comment: So it seems to work! Thanks again!

I know this is another topic, but now that I have the data pulling to the VF page (thanks to your help), any idea what style property I set to change the font size on the table?

Comment: Cool - no worries, apologies for forgetting the __r/__c, silly mistake.